# cocos2d calculate exit point based on initial point and an angle of the gun

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, angle, direction

I'm having difficulties here with calculating kind of trajectory without any physics engine.

What I'm trying to achieve is to move a cannon to a certain point. I have the cannon's initial position, angle between the cannon and the touch point + distance I want to travel.

The goal here is to calculate the exit point based on the starting point, angle and distance.

Scheme: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39096612/testcase.png

Thats how I rotate the cannon while moving the finger (behind it, not in front):

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
CGFloat angle    = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpToAngle(ccpSub(cannon.position, location)));
angle += 90;

cannonRotation = angle;
```

Usually its done with this, but it wont work for me (may be I'm doing it wrong...), really need your help here.

```
ccp(x + distance * cos(a), y + distance * sin(a))
```

Comment: Is your cannon a sprite? How do you apply cannonRotation to it?

Comment: Yes, its a sprite, I'm doing the rotation in the scheduled method like a -(void)tick:(ccTime)dt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exitPoint = ccpAdd(cannon.position , ccp(cannon.position.x - touch.x , cannon.position.y - touch.y));`

Comment: Thank you for your replay, it's not working, may be I didn't explained the goal well enough.
I've made another scheme to illustrate it better:
http://cl.ly/043A0p1G0o2j0b0r2r0g

The goal is to find dx, dy - obviously I'm on the same line crossing the cannon center but can't think of anything to solve this (Math isn't my thing) :)

Comment: Not working eighter, here is the log:

`cannon: {240, 135} - touch: {244, 68} = {4, -67} | FYI angle: 93.416588
cannon: {240, 135} - touch: {236, 224} = {-4, 89} | FYI angle: -87.426643
cannon: {240, 135} - touch: {362, 127} = {122, -8} | FYI angle: 176.248276
cannon: {240, 135} - touch: {58, 130} = {-182, -5} | FYI angle: 1.573664`